# "AttributeError: 'QgsZonalStatistics' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'" when filtering ZonalStatistics result in PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, filter, zonal-statistics, attributeerror

I want to calculate zonal stats of a raster using a polygon layer and the filter the ouput as another layer.

This is the code I tried:

```py
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (tempVectorLyr, rasterLyr, '-', 1)
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)

count = math.ceil(thresholdArea / (abs(xres) * abs(yres)))

features = zoneStat.getFeatures("\"_sum\">{}".format(count))

featureLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "Flayer", "memory")
    featureLayer.setCrs(r_crs)
    pr = featureLayer.dataProvider()

    no_f = 0
    for feature in features:
        no_f = no_f + 1
        pr.addFeature(feature)
```

This was the error I got:

> AttributeError: 'QgsZonalStatistics' object has no attribute
> 'getFeatures'

I'm guessing zoneStat is not a layer, how do I save it as memory layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm guessing zoneStat is not a layer

No it's not. Your `zoneStat` variable is an instance of the `QgsZonalStatistics` class. When you call its method `calculateStatistics()`, what is returned is an enumerator code which corresponds to either success or one of several errors.

See documentation [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsZonalStatistics.html#a339d5c08f7a576123fd7a152670ba299).

If the calculation method is successful, the important thing to understand is that the statistics fields will be added to your input vector layer which you passed to the instance of `QgsZonalStatistics` in the class constructor (which in your case already appears to be a temporary memory layer), so once the calculation has run and returned 0, you can filter your input layer directly.

I would modify your code slightly to something like:

```py
...
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (tempVectorLyr, rasterLyr, '_', 1)
result = zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
if result == 0:
    count = math.ceil(thresholdArea / (abs(xres) * abs(yres)))
    features = tempVectorLyr.getFeatures("\"_sum\">{}".format(count))
    # do something with features
...
```

One other thing: There is a typo in your code- When you instantiated the `QgsZonalStatistics` class you passed `'-'` (a hyphen), as the field prefix character, but later in your `getFeatures()` expression your field name is prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks so much. This actually solved the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it solved your problem.